# plotting 3D edge in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a 3D matrix of a MRI image and used matlab edge function and it gave me a 3D [matrix](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/94718193/edge.mat) as follow which some of the points are 1 (means edges).

I want to show this surface in matlab but I don't know that how I should do this. I know that I should use surf.

[image]

Comment: Could explain the matrix `b` a bit more? why is it `30x100x100`? So there are 100 images of size `30x100`. How do you want to plot it?

Comment: I suppose you can use find to get the *height* of all the points. Then mangle it in a form surf understands.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar: as you can see in that matrix, it is a zeros matrix which some of its points are 1. So, i just want to polt those ones as a surface

Comment: @bdecaf: I used "find" and found the location of 1s, but I don't know the rest!

Comment: @Sam Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

As @bdecaf said, you can use `find` to determine the height of the points, or in other words, in which of the 100 layers does the point lie. You can do that as follows:

```
z1=zeros(30,100);
temp=find(b);
[row,col,layer]=ind2sub(size(b),temp);
for i=1:size(x,1)
   z1(row(i),col(i))=layer(i);
end
```

You can get an image as follows:

[image: Surf plot of the matrix]